# Universal documentation tool - Java (Spring MVC), Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, javadoc

I have a completed application in Java (Spring MVC) back-end and Javascript (Jquery) front-end. I started the project not having in mind documentation at all and now I am asked to write a documentation for it. From what I've read javadoc is the way to go with java but what about the javascript parts? I would like to have similar format for all the classes and methods in the code.

My question is this: Is there any tool to help me document both java and javascript code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We use JavaDOC for Spring code and JSDoc for ajax code.
It benefits us greatly as we are able to comment the relevant sections of code while developing a extensive documentation for external use.

Give that a go and see how you go.